# HTTP Response problems with Django form

Tags: python, django, forms

at the moment, I try to make a search form for a small database.

This is a part of my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
#...
class searchForm(forms.Form):
   searchField = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
#...
```

This is a part of my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
#...
def index(request):
   template = loader.get_template('index.html')
   context = Context({})
   return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

def search(request):
   if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
     form = searchForm(request.POST)# A form bound to the POST data
     if form.is_valid():
        searchData = form.cleaned_data['searchField']
        return HttpResponseRedirect('search.html') # Redirect after POST #???
   else:
     searchData = searchForm() # an unbound form

   return render(request, 'search.html', {'form': form,}) #???
#...
```

This is a part of my index.html, where I want to implement that form:

```
<label for="Search">Search:</label>
<form action = "/search/" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type = "submit" value = "Go" />  
</form>
```

What I'm trying to do:

When I submit the form I would like to redirect to the result file called search.html, where for the beginning, is the input from the search textfield showing up. The link struktur should be something like that:

Landing-Page is: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

after a submitted form: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search.html`

I think there might be an error in the search method, where I marked the lines with the '???'. The next problem is, that my search textfield isn't showing up.

Would be great, if someone could give me some advice.

thanks,
eljobso

Comment: You should redirect to an URL not a html file itself. So for your app I hazard a guess that you have `search.html` mapped to `/search/` so in that case it would be `return HttpResponseRedirect('/search/')` for now. What this leads to as a follow up and that is that you should use your namespaced URL instead of a hardcoded like the one I supplied. But this should get you going.

Comment: If you're in django 1.5, use [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView)

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: The form isn't showing up because as you say, you want it to appear in `index.html` but the `index` view isn't passing any form to the template. Is in `search` view where you pass the form the template.

If you want the behavior described you should reorganize the code like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template.context import RequestContext

#...
def index(request):
   # this will only render the template with the form
   searchData = searchForm() # an unbound form
   return render_to_response(
        'index.html',
        context_instance=RequestContext(
            request,{'form':searchData,}
        )
    )

def search(request):
   if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
     form = searchForm(request.POST)# A form bound to the POST data
     if form.is_valid():
        searchData = form.cleaned_data['searchField']
        # do whatever you want to process the search with
        # searchada, maybe populate some variable
        return render_to_response(
            'search.html',
            context_instance=RequestContext(
                request,{'form':searchData,} # maybe add here the populated variable with the search
            )
        )
   else:
     # request.GET, just show the unbound form
     searchData = searchForm() # an unbound form

   return render_to_response(
        'search.html',
        context_instance=RequestContext(
            request,{'form':searchData,}
        )
    )
```

Then your templates should be:

## index.html

```
<!-- is not good to have a label outside form -->
<label for="Search">Search:</label>
<form action = "/search/" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type = "submit" value = "Go" />  
</form>
```

And also that text included inside `search.html` template because there you render the form as well.

I hope this may bring some light!

Answer (score 1):

With django [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView) you can do that:

```
class Index(FormView):
    form_class = SearchForm
    template_name = 'index.html'
    success_template = 'search.html' # I've added this attr

    def form_valid(self, form): #That return a your form, validated
      # Here you can do something with you VALID form.
      searchData = form.cleaned_data['searchField']
      context = dict(
            searchData=searchData,
        )
      return render_to_response(self.success_template, {}, RequestContext(self.request, context))
```